# Do passive buzzers require a PWM pin?

Tags: buzzer

[This guide](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/SURYATEJA/use-a-buzzer-module-piezo-speaker-using-arduino-uno-89df45)   Shows how to wire a passive buzzer to be used with tone(). I notice they have it wired to D9, which is a PWM pin. But is it required to use a PWM capable digital output pin to play tones from a passive buzzer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't need to be a PWM pin. `tone()` uses a timer and an interrupt to generate the audio signal and can work with any IO pin.